# Unity 3d GO orientation

Tags: c#, dot, dot-product

I look for the best way to detect, what site of an GO (cube) is facing upwards.
My research led me to the Dot-product.
I know what I want to do, but I guess my c# skills are too bad..

Basically I just want to find the Dot-product for example for the x-rotation.
And if its between a value of 0,9 to 1 one site is facing upwards, for -0,9 to -1 the other Site and so on for all axes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Unity's documentation you have the following [example](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Dot.html). You just have to tweak it a little bit in order to achieve what you need.

```
// detects if other transform is behind this object

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform other;

    void Update()
    {
        if (other)
        {
            Vector3 forward = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
            Vector3 toOther = other.position - transform.position;

            if (Vector3.Dot(forward, toOther) < 0)
            {
                print("The other transform is behind me!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I already found it and I fail at tweaking it to the rotation instead of the position. I tried vector3 up and eulerAngles but I cant get it to work.
I know that this is not a proper question but I cant figure out, how to tweak the code for rotations.

Comment: Have you tried `transform.up`, `transform.front` or `transform.right` etc? You have to trigger them within c# script that is attached to your object